# How to match argument reference in Google Mock

Tags: c++, googlemock

I am newer for google mock. Now I have one question about how to match the argument reference? here are the codes

```
class Parameter {
public:
    int m_idata;
    char m_cdata;
    bool Parameter::operator ==(const Parameter& element) const {
        return (m_idata == element.m_idata && m_cdata == element.m_cdata);
    }
};

class FooInterface {
public:
    virtual ~FooInterface() {}

    virtual void SetParameter(Parameter& val) = 0;
};

// mock class
class MockFoo: public FooInterface {
public:        
    MOCK_METHOD1(SetParameter, void(Parameter& val));
};

TEST(FooTest, setParameterTest) {   
    MockFoo mockFoo;

    EXPECT_CALL(mockFoo, SetParameter(An<Parameter&>())); // How to match argument reference???

    Parameter para;
    mockFoo.SetParameter(para);  // there is an exception here, why???
}
```

and I also tried the following to match `SetParameter()`:

```
Parameter test_para;
EXPECT_CALL(mockFoo, SetParameter(Ref(test_para)));
```

And

```
EXPECT_CALL(mockFoo, SetParameter(A<Parameter&>()));
```

And

```
Parameter test_para;
test_para.m_cdata = 'c';
test_para.m_idata = 10;
EXPECT_CALL(mockFoo, SetParameter(_)).WillOnce(::testing::SetArgReferee<0>(test_para));
```

Both those two codes can also cause exception...
Could any one tell me how to match the argument reference `Parameter&` in the function `SetParameter()`?

Comment: What is the specific error or exception that you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

This was supposed to be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

The only error in your code is that you have a superfluous "Parameter::".
I tried to run the code and I didn't see any exception. It ran just fine.